# What are the optimal std::memory_orders for this scenario of a coroutine waiting on an event?

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, memory-model, relaxed-atomics

I'm working on a coroutine multiple-producers, single-consumer `Event` ([here it is, for context](https://github.com/userver-framework/userver/blob/develop/core/include/userver/engine/single_consumer_event.hpp)). Simplified:

```cpp
class WaitList {
 public:
  void Append() { coro_.store(GetCurrentCoro()); }
  void Remove() { coro_.store({}); }

  void WakeUp() {
    auto p = coro_.exchange({});
    if (p) p->WakeUpIfSleeping();
  }

 private:
  std::atomic<Coro*> coro_{nullptr};
};

class Event {
 public:
  void Wait() {
    waiters_.Append();
    if (IsReady()) waiters_.WakeUp();
    // fall asleep
    // ...
    // woken up
    waiters_.Remove();
  }

  void Send() {
    SetReady();
    waiters_.WakeUp();
  }

 private:
  bool IsReady() { return signal_.load(); }
  void SetReady() { return signal_.store(true); }

  WaitList waiters_;
  std::atomic<bool> signal_{false};
};
```

Please help me set the minimum required `std::memory_order`s for:

1. `Append`
2. `IsReady`
3. `SetReady`
4. `WakeUp` (talking about the `exchange`)
5. `Remove`

The primary platform is x86_64, but being optimal for other platforms is welcome. If there are multiple local minima, you can list them all (there is a finite number of theoretically possible combinations: `sizeof(std::memory_order) ^ 5`).

It seems to me that 1-4 require `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, because:

1. If `Append` and `IsReady` are reordered from the POV of `Send` thread, then after the sequence `IsReady-SetReady-WakeUp-Append` the coroutine will fall asleep forever (right?)
2. If `SetReady` and `WakeUp` are reordered from the POV of `Wait` thread, then after the sequence `WakeUp-Append-IsReady-SetReady` the coroutine will fall asleep forever (right?)

Given that we are dealing with two atomics (`coro_` and `signal_`), I'd expect `acquire-release` not to be enough.

I know it is possible to squash `coro_` and `signal_` into a single `std::uintptr_t` or something, but let's leave them as they are for the purpose of this exercise. It's not as simple in reality: there are multiple synchronization primitives all based around the same ideas, and the current layout generalizes to them well.

Comment: Can you show the usage pattern per thread? And do you use reuse the Events?

Comment: One thread calls `Wait`, and other threads call `Send`, possibly multiple times, at unrelated moments of time. All threads are guaranteed to finish before `Event` is destroyed (this part is out of scope of the question). Events can be reused, but for the sake of simplicity, let's say they cannot be reset, so the 2nd+ `Wait` operation should always wake up immediately.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what semantics are desired?  What are the conditions under which a wakeup is supposed to occur, or not occur?

Comment: The coroutine calling `Event::Wait` expects to be woken up as soon as `signal_ == true`

Comment: When a coroutine is sleeping, it wakes up (gets scheduled) as soon as `WakeUp` is called. If `WakeUp` has already been called by the time it falls asleep, it wakes up immediately. The details of how coroutine scheduling works are not very important here, I think. The main problem is how not to allow the waiter coroutine to miss an incoming signal and fall asleep forever.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420254).

Comment: If the coroutine is woken by `WakeUpIfSleeping`, why does it care about the value of `signal_`? It can't be planning to call `Wait` again immediately, because that will just call `WakeUp` exactly the same as `Send` did. I'm not sure you _need_ `signal_` and `coro_` to be as tightly coupled as they are